# Javascript - how to avoid long/ugly if/else statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning Javascript (mainly using JQuery) and was wondering if somebody could help me.

I've written an if/else statement that checks to see if a particular string appears in the URL, then posts a forms content to a particular php script depending on the string.

**Q: The code I'm using works, BUT feels clumsy and unnecessarily long! - I figure there MUST be a simpler way to write this!? I've had a look around but most answers just seem to provide code without anything to help me understand how it was done..**

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. A user completes one of 4 signup forms (prereg1.html, prereg2.html, prereg3.html, prereg4.html)
2. Depending on the URL, the if/else statement sends the form data to a corresponding PHP script (add_prereg1.php, add_prereg2.php etc.) which adds the data to an email list database (hosted by campaign monitor)

*note: My php knowledge is pretty poor too - because the campaign monitor lists each have unique IDs, the only way I can get the php to post the form data in the right list is to have 4 separate 'prereg.php' scripts. I'm sure there is a way to get the php script to figure out which list to post to based on the variables passed by the javasscript but this is a bit beyond me at this stage! Any pointers welcome..*

**Anyhow here is the if/else statement:**

```
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('prereg1') > -1) {
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "bin/add_prereg1.php",
                data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
            });
        } 

        else {
                if (document.location.href.indexOf('prereg2') > -1) {
                   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "bin/add_prereg2.php",
                        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
                    });
                }

            else {
                if (document.location.href.indexOf('prereg3') > -1) {
                   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "bin/add_prereg3.php",
                        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
                    });
                }

            else {
                    if (document.location.href.indexOf('prereg4') > -1) {
                       $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "bin/add_prereg4.php",
                            data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
                        });
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With a lot of reading :) preferably math, this will reveal the mathematical and logical model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
var match = window.location.href.match( /prereg(\d)/ );

if ( match ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'bin/add_prereg' + match[1] + '.php',
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
    });
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4MWDm/

You simply search the string for the sequence "prereg" followed by a digit. The parens capture the digit, so you can access it with `[1]`.

---

Btw use `window.location` instead of `document.location`.

> document.location was originally a read-only property, although Gecko
>   browsers allow you to assign to it as well. For cross-browser safety,
>   use window.location instead.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location

Comment: If the regex does not match the href, this code would cause an exception. And using `/prereg([0-4])/` would actually fit his needs much better.

Comment: Thanks for all the help chaps, its really good to see other heads working on stuff like this - helps a lot!

The code Sime suggests above seems to work fine - sorry Niko but I don;t understand your concerns with it - can you clarify?

Comment: @Niko I see no harm in allowing a few more digits. At some point in the future he may add a fifth form...

Comment: @user There should be a check whether or not a digit was found. That's what Niko meant. I've updated my answer with the check.

Comment: If you can be sure that `document.location.href` is in the form `prereg1.html` when you execute this code, it is just fine. Otherwise `match(..)` could be returning something other than an array.

Comment: @Sime  True, at some point in the future I may have to add more forms and it would be great if the script didn't need amending to add more..

SO the check you added was done by wrapping the ajax call in an if statement? - In what scenario would the previous code have failed?

Comment: @Niko, sorry your response "If you can be sure.. " just went over my head!

Comment: @Niko Excellent point. I've updated my code to cover that case.

Comment: @matt I've updated my code a few seconds ago. Be sure to use the updated version...

Comment: @Sime you may as well use `(\d+)` if you're interested in allowing for future growth.

Comment: @matt If the code were to be executed on a page that does not contain "preregN" in its URL, the `match()` method would return `null`, so accessing the digit with `match[1]` would throw an error. That's why we guard against that by enclosing the ajax call in an if-statement...

Comment: @mblase75 - how does (/d+) work to allow better for future growth?

Comment: @matt: if you someday have ten forms, `(\d)` would only match a `1` while `(\d+)` would match `10` -- the `+` matches one or more consecutive digits.

Comment: @matt If you (at some point in the future) have more than ten forms, so for instance the URL of the page contains "prereg14", `(\d)` will match only the digit `1`, whereas `(\d+)` will match `14` (all digits after "prereg".

Comment: @mblase75 ahh! Understood - the day I got to 10 forms and it stopped working would have had me banging my head trying to figure out why!
I'll add it to my code, Thanks again

Comment: @matt Actually, it wouldn't stop working, it just would call "add_prereg1.php" instead of "add_prereg10.php". I'm sure you'd figure that one out in no time. `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas You'd hope so! Though I continue surprise even myself with dumbness sometimes ;)

Comment: @matt You have StackOverflow, so no worries.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas So it seems - I've been here loads in the past to find fixes but have never had to post before - such a good resource - for all levels of experience. You guys are useful to have around, cheers  :)

Answer (score 6):

You could use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('prereg' + i) > -1) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bin/add_prereg" + i +".php",
            data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
        });

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to put the entire ajax call inside the for-loop. It would make more sense to use a for-loop just to determine the digit, and then make the ajax call *after* that.

Comment: But again, there is no need for the for-loop altogether since executing a RegExp match is more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all statements are the same, so you can generalize.

- Use the `~` trick - it returns falsy for `-1` and thruthy otherwise. This is useful in combination with `indexOf`.
- Next, the `?:` works like this: `a ? b : c` returns `b` if `a` is truthy and `c` if `a` is falsy.

Admittedly, setting the `number` variable is still kind of repetitive.

```
var href = location.href, // so that you don't have to
                          // write 'location.href' but only 'href'

    number = ~href.indexOf('prereg1') ? 1
           : ~href.indexOf('prereg2') ? 2 // if the first ~ returned falsy
           : ~href.indexOf('prereg3') ? 3 // etc.
           : ~href.indexOf('prereg4') ? 4 // etc.
           : null; // if all returned falsy

if(number) { // if not null (null is falsy so won't pass the 'if')
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/add_prereg" + number + ".php",  // insert number
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
    });
}
```

Comment: Explicitly writing `href.indexOf('preregN')` for each case (digit)? This solution can hardly be recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Using regular expressions you can simplify it to something like:

```
document.location.href.match(/prereg(.)/);
var index = RegExp.$1:

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bin/add_prereg" + index + ".php",
    data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to have a loop you can get the index from url itself according to your code,

```
var url=document.location.href;
var startIndex=url.indexOf('prereg'); 
var index=    url.substring(startIndex+5,1);//make sure your index is correct (not tested by me)



 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bin/add_prereg" + i +".php",
            data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can simply use `else if { ... }` instead of `else { if { ... } }`. The way you're doing things in your code is a little bit too complicated for my taste.

I'd rather write a function that extracts the "prereg" parts from the location string and then wrap up the jQuery `$.ajax` call after that (this way you wouldn't need to copy the code into all the then-blocks, since the only difference is the URL for the AJAX request).

If you have the string ("prereg1", "prereg2", etc.) extracted correctly, you can also use a `switch` statement instead of the if/else-cascade. If the URL is the only different it's not really worth doing any kind of flow-control in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the switch as known from other programming languages such as PHP as you mentioned

```
    switch (document.location.href) {
case 'prereg1':
// Your code here
break;

case 'prereg2':
// Your code here
break;

case 'prereg3':
// Your code here
break;

case 'prereg4':
// Your code here
break;
}
```

It doesn't really help with the rest of your code, which would still be repetitive, but in regards to all of the nested if/else statements, switches are more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if document.location.href.indexOf('prereg') > -1) {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/add_" + document.location.href + ".php",
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to pull the required piece out of the url like this:

```
var re=new RegExp(/prereg\d/);

var postUrl = 'bin/add_' + re.exec(document.location.href) + '.php';

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postUrl ,
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the number from the html filename, and construct your URL with it:

```
$.ajax({
                var pagename = location.pathname;
                var formid = pagename.substring(7,10);
                var myurl = "bin/add_prereg" + formid + ".php";
                type: "POST",
                url: myurl,
                data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email
            });
```